# Remove first column from Data Validation List based on table Headers

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, formula

I have a table with the following headers:
[image]

And I have a dropdown list that allows people to select the year with the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("BrandsMarketShares[#Headers]")
```

The problem is that it also allows people to select the "Brands" header, which makes no sense as it has a different set of values.
How can I remove the "Brands" column from the formula, but while still keeping the adaptability of the formula (the Table can expand or contract, and I don't want to change the formula constantly).

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep using `INDIRECT()` try `=DROP(INDIRECT("BrandsMarketShares[#Headers]"),,1)`

Comment: That worked, thanks!
Is there a better way than using INDIRECT?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without INDIRECT() and still be dynamic, by adding one step.  Tables have tremendous advantages but some functions have quirky behavior working with tables, such as not being able to use `[#Headers]` in data validation.  It may be easier to just do you own indirection and stop using the cumbersome INDIRECT() function:

**Approach 1**

Go into Name Manager and create a new Table Name, let's call it `Brand_Headers`, and set its value to `=BrandsMarketShares[#Headers]`.

Now, in data validation, we simply use the formula `=Brand_Headers` and it works.  To continue on with JvdV's solution for eliminating the "Brand" column header:

`=DROP(Brand_Headers,,1)`

**Approach 2**

You can also include the DROP() in the defined name:

1. Set `Brand_Headers` to `=DROP(BrandsMarketShares[#Headers],,1)` in Name Manager.
2. Just use `=Brand_Headers` in data validation as your formula.

**Note**

For others viewing this answer, remember that the DROP() function only exists in Excel O365 for now.

This naming is a one-time thing, and it is dynamic.  If you add columns to your table, `Brand_Headers` includes those columns.